# Как изменить расстояние

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброй ночи, как изменить расстояние между этими блоками?

```css
.second_list{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1200px;
    right: 20px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.list2 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.first_rectangle, .second_rectangle, .third_rectangle, .fourth_rectangle{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 251px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgb(97, 97, 97);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.flour_text, .sugar_text, .oil_text, .soon_text{
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 25.20px;
    word-wrap: break-word
}
.block_flour, .block_sugar, .block_oil, .block_soon{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="second_list">
        <ul class="list2">
            <li class="first_rectangle"><div class="block_flour"><img src="./v39_752.png" class="flour"><br><br><br><br><br><span class="flour_text">Mąka</span></div></li>
            <li class="second_rectangle"><div class="block_oil"><img src="./v39_756.png" class="oil"><br><br><br><br><br><span class="oil_text">Oley</span></div></li>
            <li class="third_rectangle"><div class="block_sugar"><img src="./v39_760.png" class="sugar"><br><br><br><br><br><span class="sugar_text">Cukier</span></div></li>
            <li class="fourth_rectangle"><div class="block_soon"><img src="./v39_764.png" class="soon"><br><br><br><br><br><span class="soon_text">Wkrótce w sprzedaży</span></div></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: Как раз таки я делал маргином и он просто на месте стоит

Comment: Это конечно вариант, но лучше `gap`, там не придётся колхозить и делать отрицательные отступы родителю, чтобы визуально ок было.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать gap: …px;

Или же ты можешь использовать margin-top: …px;
чтобы сделать отступ от верхнего бока на определенное количество пикселей.